# Is a value something to "indicate" the valued thing?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, verbs, verb-agreement, collocation

Sorry for the confusing title.

I came across the following sentence and am wondering if the word "indicate" collocates with the word "value" as in this case:

> The PCS (Print Contrast Signal) is a value that indicates the contrast between the bars and spaces.

Comment: I would have said that *the value of the PCS indicates...*

Comment: In this case *defines* would probably be a better choice than *indicates*, both in the OP and in Drew's example above.

Comment: The *reading* on a thermometer is a *value* which *indicates* the prevailing ambient temperature. The reading, itself, is *not* the temperature (which is a concrete, physical, phenomenon of molecules in particular states of excitement), but an *abstract quantity* used as a proxy to describe, concisely, the states of those innumerable ambient molecules.

Comment: Note that you can replace "value" with "number" and the meaning of the sentence will not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is, to a degree, technospeak.  The term "value" here means "number".  The magnitude of the number somehow correlates with the degree of contrast "between bars and spaces" (whatever that is).  The sentence you quote is perfectly valid.

And I suppose one could argue that, in technospeak, it's fairly common for "indicates" to follow a word or three after "value", when it's used in this sense to describe the meaning of some data item.  I don't think one can derive any deep meanings from this, though, and certainly not any "rules".